# htaccess rewrite rule /store.php?city=cityname to /cityname

Tags: .htaccess

How to write rewrite rule in htaccess file for this below functionality.

```
www.hostname.com/store.php?city=cityname ->  www.hostname.com/cityname
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+store\.php?city=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ store.php?city=$1 [QSA,L]
```